# how to make a chart in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, charts, grails-plugin

as a noob in groovy/grails , i'd like to learn how to make or use a plugin for charts .
i tried zing chart , tried the exemples , but nothing as a result , sometimes i have the area of the chart and nothing else.

So to display the chart i used zing :

```
<zing:chart type="area" width="700" height="350" container="acceptToConvertChart" data="${data}" xLabels="${labels}" effect="4" />
```

And for the script :

```
<script>    def labels = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
    def data = [
              'Visitors': [100, 300, 200, 240, 500, 100, 80],
              'Purchases': [30, 50, 12, 20, 55, 20, 10]
            ]</script>
```

when i use it , nothing hapen , the area just disapear

for include :

```
 <zing:include/>
```

and it's underlined in yellow like every thing that's in relation with zing chart and when i hover it ,it says that zing is unknown , so what i should do?

Please help .

When you explain ,just know that i am not  java developper .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this in your HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
    <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
    ZC.LICENSE =["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9","ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];   </script>
</head>
<body>
    Here is your ZingChart:
    <div id='myChart'></div>
</body>
```

and something like this javascript:

```
zingchart.THEME = "classic";
var myConfig = 
    {
        "type": "area",
        "background-color": "#fff",
        "stacked": false,
        "title": {
            "text": "Visitors & Sales",
            "background-color": "#fff",
            "font-color": "#05636c",
            "adjust-layout":true
            },
        "tooltip": {
            "visible": false
        },
        "plot": {
            "aspect": "stepped",
            "line-width": "1px",
            "marker": {
                "visible": false
            },
            "hover-state": {
                "visible": false
            },
            "shadow": false
        },
        "plotarea": {
            "margin": "dynamic"
        },
        "scale-x": {
            "values": [
               "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
            ],
            "line-color": "#000",
            "line-width": "1px",
            "guide": {
                "visible": false
            },
            "tick": {
                "line-color": "#000",
                "line-width": "1px"
            },
            "label": {
                "text": "Days of the Week",
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "helvetica",
                "font-weight": "normal",
                "offset-y": "5%",
                "font-color":"#05636c"
            },
            "item": {
                "font-color": "#05636c",
                "font-weight": "normal",
                "font-family": "helvetica",
                "font-size": "12px",
                "offset-y": "3%"
            }
        },
        "scale-y": {
            "values": "0:600:50",
            "line-color": "#000",
            "line-width": "1px",
            "tick": {
                "line-color": "#000",
                "line-width": "1px"
            },
            "label": {
                "text": "Volume",
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "helvetica",
                "font-weight": "normal",
                "font-color":"#05636c"
            },
            "item": {
                "font-color": "#05636c",
                "font-weight": "normal",
                "font-family": "helvetica",
                "font-size": "12px",
                "offset-x": "-5%"
            },
            "guide": {
                "visible": false
            }
        },
        "crosshair-x": {
            "line-color": "#ffffff",
            "marker": {
                "visible": false
            },
            "plot-label": {
                "text": "<strong>%v</strong> %t",
                "shadow": 0,
                "font-size": "12px",
                "font-color": "#05636c",
                "font-family": "helvetica",
                "border-width": "1px",
                "border-color": "#05636c",
                "background-color": "#ffffff",
                "text-align": "center"
            },
            "scale-label": {
                "font-size": "12px",
                "font-color": "#000000",
                "font-family": "helvetica",
                "background-color": "#ffffff",
                "offset-y": "3%"
            }
        },
        "series": [
            {
                "values": [
                    30, 50, 12, 20, 55, 20, 10
                ]
            },
            {
                "values": [
                  100, 300, 200, 240, 500, 100, 80]
            }
        ]
    };

zingchart.render({ 
  id : 'myChart', 
  data : myConfig, 
  height: 300, 
  width: 500 
});
```

please take a look at this [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rpuoxnp6/3/)

note that you will probably have for populate the section
    "values": [
                        30, 50, 12, 20, 55, 20, 10
                    ]
with your actual values coming from your grails controller

Comment: Could you please add more details to your answer?

Comment: If you take a quick look at the [zingchart homepage](https://www.zingchart.com/) on the javascript examples, you will find that zingchart requires only 4 things: 1) direct access or a remote link (CDN) to the zingchart.js library, 2) in you HTML (or likewise in your JSP) page a reference to this library 3) the chart element (identified by an unique id) and 4) a script section which includes both the desired configuration for your zingchart (formatting etc.) as well as the data to be displayed in your chart. Once you have the hard-coded JSP working in Grails, move the data into your controller.